# Eager Load without a formal ActiveRecord association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, eager-loading

I have a Record class and Pay Period class, each with a start_time and end_time.

I'm grabbing a range of Records using

```
Record.where(start_time: s..e)
```

I run into a N+1 query issue because when i loop through these Records, i do a query for it's Pay Period. Pay Periods can't overlap, so a Record can have one or no Pay Period; but they are not linked to Record with any coded Active Record Association. My query for finding the Pay Period:

```
PayPeriod.where(%q{ (start_time, end_time) OVERLAPS (?, ?) }, self.start_time, self.end_time).first
```

The Classes:

```
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
   ...
   validates :start_time, presence: true
   validates :end_time, presence: true
   ...
end    


class PayPeriod < ActiveRecord::Base
   ...
   validates :start_time, presence: true
   validates :end_time, presence: true
   ...
end
```

I know I need to preload the PayPeriods with the Records. I'm just really struggling on how to do it.

Comment: whats the association between the paypriods and records

Answer (score 0):

You can always use plain SQL as an argument to the `where` method. Just note that the table names are plural usually.

I guess that a `Record` has many `PayPeriods` then it might look like:

```
Record.where(start_time: (start_time..end_time))
      .joins(pay_periods)
      .where('(pay_periods.start_time, pay_periods.end_time) OVERLAPS (records.start_time, records.end_time)')
```